# Convert to string to byte array in c# and form byte array to string in java

Tags: java, c#, arrays, string, byte

I have client server setup, Client is in C# and server is in Java.
Now I am encoding a string into a byte array and sending it to a Java server, but when Java decodes it receives a `String` with a space after each character:

```
Sending PLAIN  >>>>> Received P L A I N
```

C# code (sender):

```cs
static byte[] GetBytes(string str) {
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    // System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Java code (receiver):

```java
protected SaslResponse receiveSaslMessage() throws TTransportException {
     underlyingTransport.readAll(messageHeader, 0, messageHeader.length);
     byte statusByte = messageHeader[0];
    // Bytes for C# code received here
    byte[] payload = new byte[EncodingUtils.decodeBigEndian(messageHeader, STATUS_BYTES)];
    underlyingTransport.readAll(payload, 0, payload.length);

    NegotiationStatus status = NegotiationStatus.byValue(statusByte);
    if (status == null) {
        sendAndThrowMessage(NegotiationStatus.ERROR, "Invalid status " + statusByte);
    } else if (status == NegotiationStatus.BAD || status == NegotiationStatus.ERROR) {
        try {
            String remoteMessage = new String(payload, "UTF-8");
            throw new TTransportException("Peer indicated failure: " + remoteMessage);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new TTransportException(e);
        }
    }

    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled())
        LOGGER.debug(getRole() + ": Received message with status {} and payload length {}",
               status, payload.length);
    return new SaslResponse(status, payload);
}

protected void handleSaslStartMessage() throws TTransportException, SaslException {
    // call upper method
    SaslResponse message = receiveSaslMessage();

    LOGGER.debug("Received start message with status {}", message.status);
    if (message.status != NegotiationStatus.START) {
        sendAndThrowMessage(NegotiationStatus.ERROR, "Expecting START status, received " + message.status);
    }

    // Bytes converted to string here - Received P L A I N
    String mechanismName = new String(message.payload);

    TSaslServerDefinition serverDefinition = serverDefinitionMap.get(mechanismName);
    LOGGER.debug("Received mechanism name '{}'", mechanismName);

    if (serverDefinition == null) {
        sendAndThrowMessage(NegotiationStatus.BAD, "Unsupported mechanism type " + mechanismName);
    }
    SaslServer saslServer = Sasl.createSaslServer(serverDefinition.mechanism,
    serverDefinition.protocol, serverDefinition.serverName, serverDefinition.props,
    serverDefinition.cbh);
    setSaslServer(saslServer);
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `UTF8`, not `UTF-8` string, i.e. `String remoteMessage = new String(payload, "UTF8");`

Comment: Is the C# appending a `nul` character, i.e. `\0`?

Comment: I doubt c# is adding them, but it can be easily be checked with hex editor ?

Comment: There are some threads about this same topic floating around SO and the net, run a quick search, and come back if it doesn't help. Here's one of them : [http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/244429-Sending-UTF-8-between-Java-and-C](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/244429-Sending-UTF-8-between-Java-and-C)

Comment: Are those really SPACEs after each character, and not a 0 character?

You could output the byte array (e.g. to a file) before sending it, and output the received byte array on receiving it, and check them in a hex editor (should be one byte per character for ASCII characters). If they're different, something in the transport is modifying it.

In *handleSaslStartMessage* , you're using the default CharSet. It's probably UTF-8 but you could specify it if in doubt.

"UTF-8" *is* the correct name AFAIK. (See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all add debug into C# code:

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str) {
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    // System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Base64 debug: " + Convert.ToBase64String(data));
    return bytes;
}
```

Then the same into Java code:

```
// Bytes converted to string here - Received P L A I N
System.out.println("Base64 debug: " + new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(message.payload));
String mechanismName = new String(message.payload);
```

Finally replace:

```
//String mechanismName = new String(message.payload);
String mechanismName = new String(message.payload, "UTF-8");
```